Scaling of different kernels when estimating densities in R
The implementation of the density function in R says that the kernels are scaled so that the bandwidth becomes the standard deviation of the smoothing kernel.
For the Gaussian kernel, it is dnorm(x, sd = bandwidth). So this is fine.
For the rectangular kernel, the user-supplied bandwidth has been adjusted as a = bandwidth * sqrt(3)  and has performed ifelse(abs(x) < a, .5/a, 0) }.
What is the purpose of creating a new variable as a? Is it to have a kernel with sd = bandwidth? Can someone explain this mathematically?
What is the purpose of making different kernels to have the same standard deviation?
This question is related to here. But I am seeking more explanation than what is given stated there.

What parts does the question you refer to explain or not explain? Can you elaborate?
